# Array does not show up when called?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

In my code I created a class called Inventory to store my information in an array. I created a method to add strings, and a method to display all the information stored in the array. Something went wrong along the way for my code will execute, but it will not show any of the information that I stored in the array, just a blank command window. Here is the man class.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inventory playersInventory = new Inventory();
        playersInventory.addInventory("Knife");
        playersInventory.addInventory("Food");
        playersInventory.addInventory("Water");

        playersInventory.displayInventory();
    }
}
```

and here is the Inventory class

```
public class Inventory {

    private String[] inventoryItem = new String[10];

    public void addInventory(String item){

        int x = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (inventoryItem[x]== null){
                item = inventoryItem[x];
                break;
            }
            else {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayInventory(){
        int x = 0;
        while (true){
            if (inventoryItem[x] == null){
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(inventoryItem[x] + "\n");
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the question title I understand that you don't know whether the array appear or not. How can we know??

Comment: I guess you want `inventoryItem[x] = item;` instead of `item = inventoryItem[x];`. And you probably want to make the `item` parameter final to let the compiler complain about such errors (assigning to a parameter).

Comment: Why you don't use ArrayList ?

Comment: You also should be very careful with `while(true)` since you can easily create an endless loop here. Better use `for( String item : inventoryItem )` for reading and `for( int x = 0; x < inventoryItem.length; x++ )` for writing. And yet better: use a `List<String>` and just add new items to the list, no check for null is needed and you can add more than 10 items if you want to (otherwise check the list size before adding) - just to name a few advantages.

Comment: Those `while (true)` loops are not a good idea. Your code will fail with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if none of the array elements are `null`. Loop over the array instead: `for (int x = 0; x < inventoryItem.length; x++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
item = inventoryItem[x];
```

The `=` evaluate the expression on the right and assigns the result to the variable on the left. So what you're doing there is assigning `inventoryItem[x]` to `item`.

In other words, you are not mutating the array, but assigning a new value to the parameter, which does practically nothing.

I guess you want to add the parameter into the array. So your assignment statement should be the other way around:

```
inventoryItem[x] = item;
```

Actually, to avoid confusion, just use an `ArrayList`!

```
public class Inventory {

    private ArrayList<String> inventoryItem = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addInventory(String item){
        inventoryItem.add(item);
    }

    public void displayInventory(){
        for (Sting item: inventoryItem) {
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.println(item + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't that much cleaner?

Comment: Such a simple mistake I should have caught thanks so much. Also thanks for the extra information about ArrayLists, I was not aware of those until now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code

```
  item = inventoryItem[x];
```

should be

```
  inventoryItem[x] = item;
```

You are assigning   `inventoryItem[x];` to `item` where as you need the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You did not put the item in the array "inventoryItem", Hence no information was displayed.

Change your code to following to populate the array

```
        if (inventoryItem[x]== null){
            inventoryItem[x]=item ;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't ask to "try". Give a definitive solution, else don't answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13077060)

Comment: @activatedgeek thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign value inventoryItem[x] = item;